# Conditionally cast of generic view controller fails

Tags: ios, swift, casting

Say I have the following:

```
class ContentSelectableViewController<T: NSManagedObject> : UIViewController { //... }

class PersonSelectionViewController: ContentSelectableViewController<Person> { // ... }

class PlaceSelectionViewController: ContentSelectableViewController<Place> { // ... }
```

Then in an instance of one of these subclasses, I have some code:

```
if let navCtrl = self.navigationController {


    for viewController in navCtrl.viewControllers.reversed() {

        if viewController is ContentSelectableViewController {
            log.info("Worked for \(viewController.description)")
        }

        if let vc = viewController as? ContentSelectableViewController {
            // This should be equivalent to the above.
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, when I have a stack full of subclasses of this generic baseclass, it doesn't always return true (go into the if statement) when checking if they are of type `ContentSelectableViewController` and I don't understand why.  They inherit from the same baseclass.

EDIT:

I'm guessing it's because of the generic nature of the class.  The if statements evaluate to true for the subclass that calls it.

Comment: both are different for "is" condition you are checking  viewController type  is equal to ContentSelectableTableViewController and in second condition you are casting   viewController to  ContentSelectableTableViewController.

Comment: Yes, I know.  That was not the question.  The question was why will those if statements evaluate to true for one subclass of the generic, but not the other.

Answer (score 0):

So, it does in fact have something to do with trying to type check a generic class.  It would work for the one and not the other because the one making the call implicitly adds its type.

i.e.  (Pseudo-Swift)

`if viewController is ContentSelectableViewController<Person> { //... }`

What I did instead was to define a protocol that ultimately makes these `ContentSelectableViewController<T>` selectable:

```
enum ContentSelectionRole: Int {
    case none = 0 // no selection going on right now.
    case root  // i.e. the one wanting content
    case branch // an intermediary.  think of a folder when looking for a file
    case leaf  // like a file
}

enum ContentSelectability: Int {
    case noSelections = 0
    case oneSelection = 1
    case multipleSelections = 2
}

protocol ContentSelection {

    var selectedObjects: [NSManagedObject] { get set }
    var selectionRole: ContentSelectionRole { get set }
    var selectionStyle: ContentSelectability { get set }
    func popToSelectionRootViewController() -> Bool
    func willNavigateBack(from viewController: UIViewController)
}
```

Making the definition:

```
class ContentSelectableViewController<T: NSManagedObject> : UIViewController, ContentSelection { //... }
```

And then, refactored the original post, to get:

```
@discardableResult func popToSelectionRootViewController() -> Bool {

    if let navCtrl = self.navigationController {

        for viewController in navCtrl.viewControllers.reversed() {

            if let vc = viewController as? ContentSelection {
                if vc.selectionRole == .root {

                    vc.willNavigateBack(from: self)
                    navCtrl.popToViewController(viewController, animated: true)
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false
}
```

I still don't quite understand the aspect of the language that makes it fail, but this solution works.

Protocol-based Programming seems to be more Swifty anyway...